# Connect and Bind on same socket

Tags: zeromq

I have a set of nodes running in a decentralised manner. Currently I am using one dealer socket for taking input in and one for outputting to the other nodes.

The one taking input is bound to a port, the other connects to the remainder.

I was wondering whether it is possible to roll both into one, bind to the port and connect to all the others:

```
socket = ...
socket.bind("tcp://*:5000")
for addr in other_endpoints:
  socket.connect(addr)
```

I'm expecting this to not be possible, but I'd be happily surprised if it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to bind and connect on a single socket. I have production systems running where a single socket binds over IPC and connects over PGM. The zeromq patterns do no care how (direction etc) the underlying connection was established.